# CircleCI is not running 'npm run' commands

Tags: node.js, circleci, npm-run

I'm facing issues implementing a CI/CD pipeline with CircleCI. I'm not able to execute any 'npm run' commands in the pipeline whereas these commands run on my local system.

I have built an Angular Client and Node/ Express API. And my folder structure is setup in the following way.

```
 - .circleci
   -- config.yml 
 - client
 - server
 - package.json
```

In the pipeline 'cd client npm install' works whereas 'cd client npm run build' does not work. My Angular project has 'build' script with the command set to 'ng build'.

But still the log in CircleCI reads 'npm ERR! Missing script: "build"'

The same is the case with my server folder commands. Another interesting thing to note is if I create a script named 'installapp' and use the command 'npm install' as its value, the log will now read 'npm ERR! Missing script: "installapp"'. So 'npm install' works but not 'npm run installapp' even though they both finally execute 'npm install'.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? I'm sharing my config.yml and all the package.json files for reference to help solve this error.

.circleci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.1.0
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@1.3.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: "cimg/base:stable"
    steps:
      - node/install
      - checkout
      - aws-cli/setup
      - run:
          name: Front-End Install
          command: |
            npm run frontend:install
      - run:
          name: Back-End Install
          command: |
            npm run backend:install
      - run:
          name: Front-End Build
          command: |
            npm run frontend:build
      - run:
          name: Back-End Build
          command: |
            npm run backend:build
      - run:
          name: Deploy App
          command: |
            npm run frontend:deploy
            npm run backend:deploy
```

Root application's package.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "frontend:install": "cd client && npm install",
        "backend:install": "cd server && npm install",
        "frontend:build": "cd client && npm run build",
        "backend:build": "cd server && npm run build",
        "frontend:deploy": "cd client && npm run deploy",
        "backend:deploy": "cd server && npm run deploy"
    }
}
```

client package.json (Angular)

```
{
  "name": "guitar-store-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "deploy": "chmod +x ./bin/deploy.sh && ./bin/deploy.sh"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "w3-css": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

server package.json (Node/Express)

```
{
  "name": "storefront-backend-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An e-commerce API",
  "main": "build/server/app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.17.1",
    "npm": ">=6.14.13"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.ts",
    "prettier": "prettier --config .prettierrc src/**/*.ts --write",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "jasmine": "jasmine",
    "test-local": "set ENV=test&& db-migrate db:create guitar_shop_test && db-migrate --env test up && npm run jasmine && db-migrate db:drop guitar_shop_test",
    "start": "node build/server/app.js",
    "deploy": "chmod +x ./bin/deploy.sh && ./bin/deploy.sh"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/siddube/full-stack-app-server.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Image",
    "Resize"
  ],
  "author": "siddube",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/siddube/full-stack-app-server/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/siddube/full-stack-app-server#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.7.7",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/pg": "^8.6.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.2",
    "db-migrate-pg": "^1.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-ts": "^0.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "db-migrate": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jasmine": "^3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.5",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.ts",
    "reporter.ts"
  ]
}
```

I think the main issue is I am not able to run 'npm run' scripts defined in these files. When the log prompts me to check available npm run commands, all these commands do show up. And 'npm install' works fine.

Would really appreciate some help or suggestions to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I apologise, but this is a real CircleCI rookie mistake. My client and server folders were git repositories themselves and the root app would create empty folders for them while instantiating the pipeline. Solved it by creating two new folders and copying files without the old git repositories and it is working fine.

In my defense this was the first time I'm implementing a CI/CD pipeline.